# Why won't my stack navigator show up?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to use a `StackNavigator` in my program.  Inside `Login.js` file, I attempt to use a `<Button/>` to make this happen but it won't work.   I'm getting the error below.  Why's that happening?  I'm following https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html by the way.

Here's `index.ios.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View} from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Application from './pages/Application';
import store from './redux';
import api from './utilities/api';
import StackNavigator from 'react-navigation';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import About from './pages/About';

const App = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: Login },
    Profile: { screen: About },
});

export default class DApp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            isLoading: true
        }
        console.log("something");
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        api.getData().then((res) => {
            this.setState({
                data: res.data
            })
        });
    }

    render() {
        if(this.state.isLoading) {
            console.log("The data is: " + this.state.data);
        } else {
            console.log("Else got executed");
        }

        return (
            <View>
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <Application/>
                </Provider>
                <App/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('DApp', () => DApp);
```

Here's `Login.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { ScrollView, Text, TextInput, View, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { login } from '../redux/actions/auth';
import {AuthenticationDetails, CognitoUser, CognitoUserAttribute, CognitoUserPool} from '../lib/aws-cognito-identity';
import About from './About';

const awsCognitoSettings = {
    UserPoolId: 'something',
    ClientId: 'something'
};

class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            page: 'Login',
            username: '',
            password: ''
        };
    }

    // get alt () {
    //     return (this.state.page === 'Login') ? 'SignUp' : 'Login';
    // }

    get alt() {
        if(this.state.page == 'Login') {
            return 'SignUp';
        } else {
            return 'Login';
        }
    }

    handleClick (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const userPool = new CognitoUserPool(awsCognitoSettings);

        // Sign up
        if (this.state.page === 'SignUp') {
            const attributeList = [
                new CognitoUserAttribute({ Name: 'email', Value: this.state.username })
            ];
            userPool.signUp(
                this.state.username,
                this.state.password,
                attributeList,
                null,
                (err, result) => {
                    if (err) {
                        alert(err);
                        this.setState({ username: '', password: '' });
                        return;
                    }
                    console.log(`result = ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
                    this.props.onLogin(this.state.username, this.state.password);
                }
            );
        } else {
            const authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
                Username: this.state.username,
                Password: this.state.password
            });
            const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser({
                Username: this.state.username,
                Pool: userPool
            });
            cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
                onSuccess: (result) => {
                    console.log(`access token = ${result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken()}`);
                    this.props.onLogin(this.state.username, this.state.password);
                },
                onFailure: (err) => {
                    alert(err);
                    this.setState({ username: '', password: '' });
                    return;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    togglePage (e) {
        this.setState({ page: this.alt });
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return(
            <ScrollView style={{padding: 20}}>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 27}}>{this.state.page}</Text>
                <TextInput
                    placeholder='Email Address'
                    autoCapitalize='none'
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    autoFocus={true}
                    keyboardType='email-address'
                    value={this.state.username}
                    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ username: text })} />
                <TextInput
                    placeholder='Password'
                    autoCapitalize='none'
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                    value={this.state.password}
                    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ password: text })} />
                <View style={{margin: 7}}/>
                <Button onPress={(e) => this.handleClick(e)} title={this.state.page}/>
                <View style={styles.firstView}>
                    <Text onPress={(e) => this.togglePage(e)} style={styles.buttons}>
                        {this.alt}
                    </Text>
                    <Button
                        title="Go to about"
                        onPress={() =>
                            navigate('About', { name: 'About' })
                        }
                    />
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    buttons: {
        fontSize: 12,
        color: 'blue',
        flex: 1
    },

    firstView: {
        margin: 7,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
});

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        isLoggedIn: state.auth.isLoggedIn
    };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onLogin: (username, password) => { dispatch(login(username, password)); }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

Comment: what is `props.navigation` and how are you passing that?

Comment: You forgot to set `initialRouteName`

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 1):

You are not importing StackNavigator correctly. `import { StackNavigator } from ‘react-navigation’;`

Comment: Thanks I did that.  But now I get a different error that says `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate)` in my simulator.

Comment: Please post details about the error, e.g where is it happening.

Comment: here? -> `const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;`

Comment: In `Login.js`, It's saying `const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;` is undefined.

Comment: @btzr yeah right there.

Comment: try this: `const navigate = this.props.navigation`

Comment: @btzr I already tried that, it doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like you are not setting up Login component with react-navigation correctly. Can you update the snippets with the latest code you have?

Comment: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html#sec_overview-destructuring

Comment: @hyb175 My latest code is in my original post.  The only thing I changed is `const navigate = this.props.navigation`.  Rest is the same.  I'm guessing at this point, there's a problem in `index.ios.js` in terms of using the `<Login/>` component there.

Comment: My guess is you are using Login.js in your application.js. Try getting rid of <Application /> and see if the error persists.

Comment: @hyb175 I need that there because it authenticates new user accounts

Comment: Are you rendering Login component in your Application component as well? Navigators will render the components for you and wrap them with a navigation prop to control navigation.